# prevent Mustache from loading template from cache

Tags: backbone.js, mustache

I'm using Backbone.js with mustache.js, and I'm loading my templates using ajax. my problem is that the templates are being loaded from cache(refreshing using ctrl+F5 if that matters!). Now I have made changes to the template but it's still loading the old version of it. It's working perfectly fine in incognito. Is there a way to prevent this? Maybe prevent Mustache from caching the template?

The code that renders the template is:

```
$.get(this.templatesPath + this.template, function(resTemplate){
        var html = Mustache.render(resTemplate, that.personData);
        that.$el.html(html);
    });
```

My first thought was to use some other function instead of "Mustache.render()" like maybe "Mustache.to_html()". But looking at the 
Source Code
reveals that to_html() merely calls render().

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you're using Chrome, there's a special option in the console to disable the cache. Also, the console has to be shown when refreshing for it to work.

Comment: I am using chrome, but I'm concerned about the problem occurring on the live server for other users. I used to use Smarty before as a template engine. And tones of issues happened regarding caching, I just don't want that to happen again.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for digging up this very old question, but I was searching for the answer to a similar question and didn't end up finding it anywhere. This question is one of the first that shows up when searching "mustache disable caching".

I am using Mustache and Express with the mustache-express module. I was able to disable caching with the following:

```
const Mustache = require('mustache-express')();
delete Mustache.cache;
```

I hope this helps someone else in the future.